# I have a problem oh login in php. When I test it in localhost, login page it worked. But when I upload it on server and test, it did not worked

Tags: php, authentication, redirect, header

I have a problem oh login in php. When I test it in localhost, login page it worked. But when I upload it on server and test, it did not worked. When I test it on server, I notice that username and password entered is all correct, but it stuck at header("Location:dashboard.php");. after login, it did not redirect to the page. Can someone help me trying to solve this problem because I new on using php.

```
    <?php  
 $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "mydb");  
 session_start();  
 
 if(isset($_POST["login"]))  
 {  
      if(empty($_POST["username"]) && empty($_POST["password"]))  
      {  
           echo '<script>alert("Both Fields are required")</script>'; 
           echo '<script>window.location.href = "login.php";</script>';
      }  
      else  
      {  
           $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["username"]);  
           $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["password"]);  
           $password = md5($password);  
           $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$password'";  
           $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);  
           if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)  
           {  
                $_SESSION['username'] = $username;  
                header("location:dashboard.php");  
           }  
           else  
           {  
                echo '<script>alert("Wrong User Details")</script>';  
                echo '<script>window.location.href = "login.php";</script>';
           }  
      }  
 }  
 ?>
```

Comment: Hard to help without seeing any of the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `header('Location: dashboard.php');` (with capital `L`)

Comment: Its worked! Thank you  just a little caps lock can solve everything.